# How to Make Gmail Remember my User ID and Passwords with Safari

Tags: safari, gmail, password, autosave

I work in marketing and have several Gmail accounts established exclusively for my clients advertising programs that I must access frequently. Until a few days ago, each time I opened any Gmail account the User ID (Gmail address) and password have remained saved and would populate as I entered the first character of the Gmail address I was attempting to open.

When a colleague asked me to open her Gmail account during a time when her system was down, I unintentionally clicked "never for this Web site" when Safari asked if I wanted to save her logon information and password. I realize now that I had clicked the wrong option and since that time none of the Gmail accounts are saved requiring that I enter the full address and password each time.

I've followed the instructions on the help menu but nothing has worked. I use Safari version 6.0.4 and Mac OSX version 10.7.5. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There are three solutions I've found. The first two are the easiest and least intrusive, the **third one should be tried last** as it will remove **all** saved passwords for other websites too *(but the third seems to have worked the most times for other people)*

### [a. Safari Preferences](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19867732#19867732)

> Locate and **delete** the entry for Gmail that is set to 'Passwords
>   Never Saved':
>
> [image: Safari Password Preferences]

### [b. Remove Keychain Entry](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060717051050401)

> open Keychain Access (in Utilities), then look in the login keychain
>   and find the site you tried to visit. Somewhere in the list, you'll
>   see an entry like this:
>
> ```
> www.somesite.com (Passwords not saved)
> ```
>
> Simply delete that item from the login keychain, restart Safari, and
>   Safari will prompt you to save usernames and passwords when logging in
>   to that site. The easiest way to find it in Keychain Access is to
>   search for it using part of the website's URL as your search term.

### [c. Reset Safari](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/qdcXw5YqFAE/yEEJtRGxPHcJ)

> 1. Open Safari
> 2. Click Safari > Reset safari
> 3. Tick `Remove saved names & passwords`
> 4. Click Reset Safari
> 5. Quit, Repoen and load Gmail

Comment: You are incredible! The first option worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy to note it as such; as soon as I figure out where!

Comment: Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.